# How to testing Spring validator with Junit and Mockito

Tags: spring, testing, junit, mockito

I have a Spring Validator:

```
@Component
public class AddClientAccountValidator implements Validator {

    @Autowired
    private ValidatorUtils validatorUtils;

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return UserDto.class.equals(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        UserDto user = (UserDto) target;
        validatorUtils.setParam(errors, user);

        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "username", "username.required");
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "password", "password.required");
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "confirmPassword",
                "confirmPassword.required");
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "firstName", "firstName.required");
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "lastName", "lastName.required");
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "personalId", "personalId.required");
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "city", "city.required");
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "address", "address.required");
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "email", "email.required");
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "phone", "phone.required");
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "contribution", "contribution.required");

        validatorUtils.validateAddClientAccount();
    }
}
```

In above Validator have inject to ValidatorUtils class:

```
@Component
class ValidatorUtils {

    @Autowired
    private PersonalIdValidator personalIdValidator;
    private Errors errors;
    private UserDto user;

    void setParam(Errors errors, UserDto user) {
        this.errors = errors;
        this.user = user;
    }

    void validateAddClientAccount() {
        validateAccount();
        validContributionAccount();
    }

    private void validateAccount() {
        validUsername();
        validPassword();
        validFirstName();
        validLastName();
        validPersonalId();
        validCity();
        validAddress();
        validEmail();
        validPhone();
    }
    public void validateChangePassword() {
        validChangePassword();
    }

    private void validUsername() {
        if (!user.getUsername().isEmpty()) {
            String username = user.getUsername();
            if ((username.length() < 3) || (username.length() > 40)) {
                errors.rejectValue("username", "username.format");
            }
        }
    }

    private void validPassword() {
        if (!user.getPassword().isEmpty()) {
            String password = user.getPassword();
            if ((password.length() < 3) || (password.length() > 40)) {
                errors.rejectValue("password", "password.format");
            }
            if (!password.equals(user.getConfirmPassword())) {
                errors.rejectValue("confirmPassword", "password.confirm");
            }
        }
    }

    private void validFirstName() {
        if (!user.getFirstName().isEmpty()) {
            String firstName = user.getFirstName();
            String regex = "[A-ZŁ{1}]+[a-zł]+";
            boolean validFirstName = Pattern.matches(regex, firstName);
            if ((firstName.length() < 3) || (firstName.length() > 40) || !validFirstName) {
                errors.rejectValue("firstName", "firstName.format");
            }
        }
    }

    private void validLastName() {
        if (!user.getLastName().isEmpty()) {
            String lastName = user.getLastName();
            String regex = "[A-ZĆŁŚŻŹ{1}]+[a-ząćęłńóśżź]+";
            String regexWithTwoLastName = "[A-ZĆŁŚŻŹ{1}]+[a-ząćęłńóśżź]++[\\s]+[A-ZĆŁŚŻŹ{1}]+[a-ząćęłńóśżź]+";
            boolean validLastName = Pattern.matches(regex, lastName);
            boolean validWithTwoLastName = Pattern.matches(regexWithTwoLastName, lastName);
            if ((lastName.length() < 3) || (lastName.length() > 40)
                    || (!validLastName && !validWithTwoLastName)) {
                errors.rejectValue("lastName", "lastName.format");
            }
        }
    }
```

this class have more validator for field but I skipped it.

I want to test my Validator class use Junit or eventually mockito. I write this test class:

```
    @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class AddClientAccValidatorTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private AddClientAccountValidator validator;
    @Mock
    private ValidatorUtils validatoUtils;
    private UserDto userDto;
    public Errors errors;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        UserDto userDto = new UserDto();
        errors = new BeanPropertyBindingResult(userDto, "userDto");
    }

    @Test
    public void testValidate() {
        validator.validate(userDto, errors);
        assertFalse(errors.hasErrors());
    }

}
```

But when i run my test i get following Failet trace:

```
java.lang.AssertionError
at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:86)
at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:41)
at org.junit.Assert.assertFalse(Assert.java:64)
at org.junit.Assert.assertFalse(Assert.java:74)
at pl.piotr.ibank.validator.AddClientAccValidatorTest.testValidate(AddClientAccValidatorTest.java:67)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37)
at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:62)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Why I get this error? I get error in this line:

```
errors = new BeanPropertyBindingResult(userDto, "userDto");
```

And my second problem is that I can't declare multiple RunWith annotation. When I add:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
```

I can't parametrized my test using `@RunWith(Parameterized.class)`

How to solve it?

Anyone can help me? Maybe my approach is bad? What is best way to test Spring Validator with Junit?

Comment: In your test you're not adding any behaviour to the `ValidatorUtils validatoUtils`, so the mock injected into `AddClientAccountValidator validator` will be essentially no-op. Also, `UserDto userDto` will be initialised to `null`, so it definitely would not pass any of the validation rules you define. Reading Mockito documentation would be an obvious starting point. Note that the stack trace contains useful information: `AddClientAccValidatorTest.java:67`. Remember to mention which line that is in the question as it's currently not obvious (or even included)

Comment: Sorry, I paste wrong code. UserDto is initialized, and error line 67 is: `errors = new BeanPropertyBindingResult(userDto, "userDto");`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can run your test successfully without Mockito. The following code works with Spring @Configuration class (spring-test as dependency is required):

```
package foo.bar;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertFalse;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.support.AnnotationConfigContextLoader;
import org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult;
import org.springframework.validation.Errors;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public class AddClientAccValidatorTest {

    @Configuration
    static class ContextConfiguration {

        @Bean
        public AddClientAccountValidator validator() {
            return new AddClientAccountValidator();
        }

        @Bean
        public ValidatorUtils validatorUtils() {
            return new ValidatorUtils();
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    private AddClientAccountValidator validator;
    private UserDto userDto;
    public Errors errors;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        userDto = new UserDto();
        userDto.setLastName("Doe");
        userDto.setFirstName("John");
        userDto.setUsername("username");
        userDto.setPhone("phone");
        userDto.setPassword("password");
        userDto.setConfirmedPassword("password");
        userDto.setEmail("email");
        userDto.setContribution("contribution");
        userDto.setAddress("address");
        userDto.setCity("city");
        userDto.setPersonalId("personalId");
        errors = new BeanPropertyBindingResult(userDto, "userDto");
    }

    @Test
    public void testValidate() {
        validator.validate(userDto, errors);
        assertFalse(errors.hasErrors());
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also have a look on JSR-303 and validations with annotations on attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to Mock anything. While validating , we need the object which we want to validate and the errors. Create an object with required fields to validate and the errors object. For example,

```
@Test
public void shouldReturnErrorsWhenCustomObjectIsNull() {
    CustomValidator customValidator = new CustomValidator();

    Employee employee = new Employee();
    employee.setEmployeeFirstname("empName")


    Errors errors = new BeanPropertyBindingResult(employee, "employee");
    customValidator.validate(employee, errors);
    List<ObjectError> allErrors = errors.getAllErrors();
    assertTrue("Errors list size should not be null : ", allErrors.size() > 0);
    assertTrue(errors.hasErrors());
    assertNotNull( errors.getFieldError("empName") );
}
```